# How to check if database save and api call were successful?

Tags: typescript, express

im currently writing a function which calls 2 other functions.
Function 1 saves an object to a database,
function 2 does an api call.
The Api call looks like this:

```
    async createMSCalendarEntry(start: Date, end: Date, name: string, userID: number, email: string) {
    const api_url = `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/${vacationEmailforCalendar}/calendar/events`
    let graphresponse = await msRestNodeAuth.loginWithServicePrincipalSecret(`${microsoftClientIDforCalendar}`, `${microsoftSecretforCalendar}`, `${microsoftTenantIdforCalendar}`, { tokenAudience: "https://graph.microsoft.com/" })
    let token = await graphresponse.getToken()
    let newEvent = new Event(start.toISOString(), end.toISOString(), name, userID, email)
    var options = {
        url: api_url,
        json: newEvent.toGraphSchema(),
        method: "POST",
        headers: {
            'content-type': 'application/json',
            'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + token.accessToken
        }
    }
    let graphResponse = await this.doRequest(options)
    return (graphResponse)
}
async doRequest(options) {
    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
        request(options, function (error, body) {
            if (error) {
                reject(error);
            }
            else {
                resolve(body);
            }
        });
    });
}
```

And the DB action looks like this:

```
await this.dataService.TimesRepo.save(vacationDays)
```

This is a snippet of the function calling the other two:

```
            await this.createMSCalendarEntry(dates.start, dates.end, currentUser.FirstName, currentUser.Id, currentUser.Email)
            await this.dataService.TimesRepo.save(vacationDays)
            let responseMessage: string = (this.createMSCalendarEntry && this.dataService.TimesRepo.save) ? 'Vacation submitted' : 'Vacation could not be submitted'
            res.status(200).send({
                message: responseMessage,
                data: vacationDays
            })
            return
        }
        else {
            res.status(400).send("The selected vacation days are in an already planned vacation time!")
            return
        }
```

I want to send the response message if the two functions were decently executed.
The attempt I have there right now cant be right, since it just checks if the functions exist at all.

Can you provide me an alternative?
Greetings,
Leo

Answer (score 0):

You should receive response of these 2 methods and then compare to validate if both are success or not probably as,

```
const calendarResponse = await this.createMSCalendarEntry(dates.start, dates.end, currentUser.FirstName, currentUser.Id, currentUser.Email)
const saveResponse = await this.dataService.TimesRepo.save(vacationDays)
let responseMessage: string = (calendarResponse.<any-property> && saveResponse.<any-property>) ? 'Vacation submitted' : 'Vacation could not be submitted'
```

You will have to identify `<any-property>` of response object which will have value based on success / fail. You can simply `console.log()` response objects to identify that `<any-property>` should use to compare.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply! 
in my Case calendarResponse returns the object graphResponse. I tried to log createCalendar.<graphResponse> but got the error: Cannot find name 'graphResponse'. 
I made sure that there couldnt be a typing problem by let calendarResponse: any.

Comment: log here `let graphResponse = await this.doRequest(options)` as `console.log("***graphResponse***", graphResponse)` see what comes. if `request` is an axis / Ajax call it must be returning some properties like `status` and others.

Comment: At this position the graphResponse works as it should. The object gets logged correctly. 
But if I try to log it in the function calling the createMSCalendarEntry function, it just logs undefindet. Im wondering if it has something todo with the asny.

Comment: Async, Await are good no issues looks at all in code. Why are you returning `return (graphResponse)` can you try just `return graphResponse` and see.